# android image switching with animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to make a gallery-type view which will look like a image switcher having 3 images  at the same time. from these three, the middle image will be larger and other two will be transparent also the middle image will look like highlighted as seen in attached image.
 i want to do some carousel like things with animation on this.
When I press the left button(or swipe) the right image should come in the middle place with the same property which middle image was having(means it should scale to larger and removing transparency so it should look like the middle image) and the middle should go to the left (having the left image property ) And as it can facilitate more than three image in this case we will hide the other images and bring it front when left or right button has pressed(on the place of left most image place) i can accept both the cases whether the image view is moved or the image content of imageview is moved.

in current scenario  I am simply changing the source of image view and not doing any animation so i need to do the animation in this.
hope you understand the problem.

if having any problem then write i will try to provide more  information . 
so please help me how can I do this.

I think imageswitcher can do this but I don't know how to get this type of animation in this

You can see three images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkcI8.png) of ratoville and shrek and toy story when I will press left button "toy story" image should come in the middle with animation (scale and translate) and change the transparancy also and the hidden image (in case of more then 3 images) should come in place of "toy story" and "shrek" image will go on the place of ratoville(left most).

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard gallery http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html
You can customize it.